# How to use activeElement.tagName inside of DOM in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, dom, safari

while trying to build an UI for an android and ios app with phonegap i got stuck:

my function getFocus() tries to get the tagName and/or id of the element in focus by using

```
document.activeElement.tagName
```

but all browsers seems to get different results:

- Chromium (54.0.2840.87 (64-bit)) and androids Webkit return what I would expect: **"BUTTON"**
- Safari (10.0), Firefox (49.0.2) and the ios Webkit return: **"DIV"**

they all seem to look from a different starting point in the DOM.

How can i be more precise in order to get at least BUTTON from safari/ios webkit as well as chromium/ android webkit?

here is the complete example code:

***[edit] I edited one line in response to the helpful comment by user the8472 and took out an  tag that was around the  tag [/edit]***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="add">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>GetFocus</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p></p>
        <p>
            textfield1:
            <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="textfield1" />
            textfield2:
            <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="textfield2" />

            <button id="mybutton" onclick="javascript:getFocus()">get focus</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getFocus()
        {
         alert(document.activeElement.tagName);
        };

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: testing further while using .activeElement.childElementCount shows how different the browsers work:


firefox finds 1 child element
chrome and android find 0
safari and ios find 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it:

as the8472 pointed out, i should check the html specs:

button is (understandably) not properly specified in its focus behaviour:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button tells me that do not give focus to a button when clicked. that explains the described behaviour.

when i transfer the onclick="javascript:getFocus()" to the  tag for example and click on input fields (not the button of course) i get the correct and to be expected elements in focus returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="mybody" onclick="javascript:getFocus()">

    <div data-role="page" id="add">
      <div data-role="header" id="myheaderDiv">
        <h1>GetFocus</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="mydiv">

        <p id="myp">
            textfield1:
            <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="textfield1" />
            textfield2:
            <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="textfield2" />

            <button id="mybutton">get focus</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getFocus()
        {
         alert(document.activeElement.tagName);
        };

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

to identify the different elements i will later use `.activeElement.id`

Answer (score 2):

`button` inside `a` does not seem to be valid anyway. If you're doing non-specified things you shouldn't expect consistent behavior.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:

> #### 4.5.1 The `a` element
>
> Content model:
> Transparent, but there must be no *interactive content* or `a` element descendants.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2:

> *Interactive content* is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>
> a (if the href attribute is present), audio (if the controls attribute is present), **button**, details, embed, iframe, img (if the usemap attribute is present), [...]

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! you are absolutely right. i am gonna correct that in my questions.

still: the question stands also after i got rid of the <a> around the button and corrected the code to <button onclick:"javascript:getFocus()> the browsers still deliver different approaches to the DOM tree.

Comment: your comment actually led me to solve the issue. <button> is not specified to get focus by a click. only some browsers do that. i described it further below. thx! good teaching method! <3